# How do you fix "Your connections isn’t private" when opening with the Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm debugging a local site.

I'm getting the following message in chrome.

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from t.buyamerica.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

This is not new, and normally I just click `ADVANCED` and `Procced ...`

but lately it just stuck in a loop and display the error message again.

This is a local site therefore the key-pair is indeed invalid, but is there a way to by-pass this issue without installing a proper https for all my local (vagrant based) servers?

NOTE:
The current by-pass for me is to use the same domain as the original site, so that the local site is www.somesite.com, and the actual site is somesite.com

**I solved this issue as follow:**

In 
`System Preference -> Network -> WiFi -> Advanced -> Proxies` I saw that `Secure Http Proxy (HTTPS)` is checked and the value for the proxy is localhost:8888

I unchecked the Secure Http Proxy (HTTPS) and it seems to solve the issue.

NOTE: this is a specific MAC issue that apparently caused by a system upgrade (my current version is `10.10.5 (14F2511) Yosemite, MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)`)

I never set a proxy server or run any proxy on localhost:8888

Comment: Verify the domain name you're accessing is the same specified in your HTTPS certificate. Alternatively, use a self-signed certificate to rectify the certificate problem first.

Comment: Can you give more info on how to generate self-signed certificate?

Comment: Please read: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html

Comment: Could it be a [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) issue? HSTS prevents accessing a known secured site (https) over unsecured channel or bypassing the certificate check, that could explain the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You change your local domain something like http://yourdomain.test.

Don't forget the 'http'. And if you're using .dev, change it to .test